# Nextjs: How to send a custom 200 response at root when the base path is configured

Tags: next.js

I m using nextjs and have configured base path in next.config.js.
It looks something like this

```
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  output: 'standalone',
  basePath: '/new',
};
```

So now whenever I hit `http://localhost:3000/new` I get the homepage.

Howevever, when I hit `http://localhost:3000` without basePath, I get a 404.

What I want is to get a 200 response with some custom response like `OK`.
Even if I don't get the custom response text, getting 200 is required.

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First do this

```
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  output: 'standalone',
  basePath: '/new',
};
```

Just as you have done already, to the next thing you have to do is to add a middleware just at the root of the page

[image]

Then watch for the pathnames that is passed from the request

```
export async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const { nextUrl} = req;
  if(nextUrl.pathname === '/'){ 
    return NextResponse.json({hello: "world" }); 
  }
}
```

[image]